# Comma after "so" when meaning therefore

Tags: punctuation

When you use "so" as in therefore at the beginning of a sentence, should you put a comma after it?

*They are wearing helmets and uniforms adorned with badges. So, they must be soldiers.*

Comment: Sure, what is the problem?

Comment: It looks like a simple assertion that only needs one sentence: *They are wearing helmets and uniforms adorned with badges, so they must be soldiers.* But even that *one* comma is optional.